# FileSystemWatcher and Last line of textfile

Tags: c#, text-files, filesystemwatcher

I am trying to add `FileSystemWatcher` in Windows Service of my application.In my case i have a textfile which is getting updated continuously with may be one line or more than one line and Every time the file gets updated i need to read all those textfile lines that has not been read before .

I goolged and got to know that this

```
File.ReadText(@"C:\Filename.txt").Last();
```

will give me the Last line of the textfile once the file gets updated but i am not sure whether it will give all the unread line or only the last line of the textfile.Also my textfile is getting updated line by line.

In either case what will be the possible solution for this.

If the textfile is getting updated line by line will the `FileSystemWatcher` will also see that many times to get the last line added into the file.

Please help me.

Updated Code..

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Temp\LineTest.txt")) 
{
    string line;
    long pos = 0;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) 
    {
        Console.Write("{0:d3} ", pos);
        Console.WriteLine(line);
        pos += line.Length;
    }
}
```

Updated Code.

```
 public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private System.Threading.Thread _thread;
    private ManualResetEvent _shutdownEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    int lineCount;
    long previousLength = 0;
    string filepath = "C:\\Temp\\LineTest.txt";


    public void OnDebug()
    {

        OnStart(null);

    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {

        _thread = new Thread(addLogic);
        _thread.Start();


    }

    //This event is raised when a file is changed
    private void Watcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        _thread = new Thread(addlogic);
        _thread.Start();
    }


    public static string[] ReadFromFile(string filePath, int count, ref int lineCount)
    {
        lineCount += count;
        return File.ReadLines(filePath).Skip(lineCount).Take(count).ToArray();
    }
    public void addlogic()
    {
       //Add Logic Here
       //How to use lineCount here to read specific line that i am not getting

            //If all textfile gets traversed then is FileSystemWatcher
            FileSystemWatcher Watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(filepath);
            Watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            Watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(Watcher_Changed);

        }
    }



    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        _shutdownEvent.Set();
        _thread.Join();  // wait for thread to stop
    }
        }
    }
```

Comment: if you are adding multiple lines you should keep track of the lines you have read in your service. I would suggest to keep track of the lines you read yourselves always.

Comment: @bansi Line is getting added only one at a time into textfile and moreover there is not unique part in the line based on which i can segregate the read and unread line.And regarding tracking of read line ,please tell me how can i proceed.

Comment: you can store the offset of the last read, and start from there the next time.

Comment: @bansi Will you please explain and it will be very helpfull if you give a example in my case.Thanks

Comment: @bansi Please see my updated post and tell me how i can use `ReadFromFile()` method to use in `addLogic()` method.PLease help me sir

Comment: @bansi Sir I have one doubt as how to call `ReadFromFile` method inside the `_thread = new Thread(I think here we need to call that method);` but how i am not getting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just wrote a simple class to read the added lines. This actually reads anything append to the file even in the same line.

```
public class AddedContentReader
{

    private readonly FileStream _fileStream;
    private readonly StreamReader _reader;

    //Start position is from where to start reading first time. consequent read are managed by the Stream reader
    public AddedContentReader(string fileName, long startPosition = 0)
    {
        //Open the file as FileStream
        _fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        _reader = new StreamReader(_fileStream);
        //Set the starting position
        _fileStream.Position = startPosition;
    }


    //Get the current offset. You can save this when the application exits and on next reload
    //set startPosition to value returned by this method to start reading from that location
    public long CurrentOffset
    {
        get { return _fileStream.Position; }
    }

    //Returns the lines added after this function was last called
    public string GetAddedLines()
    {
        return _reader.ReadToEnd();
    }


}
```

You can call it like this.

```
private AddedContentReader _freader;

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    _freader = new AddedContentReader("E:\\tmp\\test.txt");
    //If you have saved the last position when the application did exit then you can use that value here to start from that location like the following
    //_freader = new AddedContentReader("E:\\tmp\\test.txt",lastReadPosition);

}
private void Watcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    string addedContent= _freader.GetAddedLines();
    //you can do whatever you want with the lines
}
```

Note: I have not tested this with very fast updates.

Comment: Thank you Bansi sir for such a nice explanation.I have one query as how can i call ` public long CurrentOffset` at the `Stop()` method of windows service which i can save for next start of the service.

Comment: I have added `protected override void OnStop()
        {
            lastLineReadOffset = _freader.CurrentOffset;
        }` to get the last offset at the time of closing of the service .Is it correct way.

Comment: yes you are correct. you can save it somewhere and read when the service starts again and use that value.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an idea based on what bansi suggested in the comments. It is keeping count of the number of lines that have been read in, and appending the new ones into a textbox. If your file gets extremely large this could become unwieldy.

```
private int linesProcessed;  //Variable for keeping track of your line position

private void ProcessFile( string filePath)
{
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
    if (linesProcessed != lines.Count())  //Make sure a new line was entered 
    {
        for (int i = linesProcessed ; i < lines.Count(); i++)
        {
            textBox1.AppendText(lines[i] + "\n") ;  
            linesProcessed += 1;
        }
    }
}

private void fileSystemWatcher1_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
   ProcessFile("c:\\temp\\test.txt");  //your file name here
}
```

---

Modified the OP's changed code. placed the position variable outside of the loop so that it wont get reset each time the method is run.

```
long pos = 0;
private void ProcessFile( string filePath)
{
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
    {
        string line;

        long count = 0;
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            count += 1;
            if (pos < count)
            {
                Console.Write("{0:d3} ", pos);
                Console.WriteLine(line);
                pos += 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In this case, if the service is stopped and started for any reason, you will lose count.

Comment: I have updated my post .How about using this code and till what size of text file it will work

Comment: @EladLachmi That is true, then you are looking a persisting the count external to the application, which is another question entirely.

Comment: What if i save the linecount in some different file and at the start of the service refer from there

Comment: That is what I was meaning, you will have to store it external to the application. You could even use a registry setting. Also you will need to build some criteria for resetting it.

Comment: Please have a look at the updated code of my post and tell me if it would work fine for large files or not

Comment: As far as size, the larger the file the longer it will take to read it, I am not sure of what your file size is or the frequency that it will be updated

Comment: Just added and example based on your changes. getting late see if it works for you

Comment: you can open file as Filestream and use [FileStream.Seek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.seek(v=vs.110).aspx) you dont have to read all the lines again and again, which would be a significant performance improvement.

Comment: @bansi that is true. Would be a lot more performent sounds like an answer you should add my alarm clock goes off in about 3 hrs.

Comment: I am using my phone so cant write code, but check this link you get the idea. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/371229/Live-Log-Viewer

Comment: @MarkHall As per the suggestion of yours and Mr.bansi i have updated my post with my latest code.But here i am not getting how to read line after a particular line and i am also not sure about the flow of the program to be correct.Please have a look.